# Workstation and Desktops remote control

Tags: delphi, winapi, capture

We're creating a remote control software which is working perfectly. But some screen like Winlogon and some antivirus windows showed us a blank screen. We were working around that and we figured out the needing of make a service and in this service we selected 'WinSta0' and then selected the correct desktop using OpenInputDesktop(). No errors were detected but still not working, any sugestion or a piece of code? In short, what we need is a chunk of code that capture  winlogon screen and returns us a bitmap. Thanks!

Comment: You would have to tap into the video drivers, if I'm not mistaken. The windows login screen isn't a part of the user's desktop.

Comment: A good source to study would be the VNC code - these are all solved problems : http://www.realvnc.com/download/open/

Comment: also : http://www.tightvnc.com/download.php  - another good reference for an RD server/client

Comment: Both cant read WinLogon too...